Using Ckeditor in Angular causes CommonJS or AMD dependencies optimization bailouts warning
I keep getting this warning when I run our angular library in an angular application. The library itself has ckeditor as a peerdependency and has compenents that uses ckeditor. So the app installs ckeditor in their own package.json. I'm trying to understand why this warning occurs and what I understand it's saying that ckeditor is not built on ECMAScript modules?
Warning: libname.mjs depends on '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts. For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies
I can silence this by adding the following to the angular.json, but should this really happen? As I understood ckeditor is using ECMAScript modules, or is it not? This is a link to the ckeditor angular dependency https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular/blob/master/tsconfig.json is it cause they are using moduleresolution: node?
Seeing how our lib will be used by multiple apps it does not feel good having to add the following code. Anyone who can explain this?
"allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
"ckeditor"
]

